# Cloning li's on AJAX response?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a basic example of my page:

I have a list on my page:

```
<ul>
 <li>title 1 <img src="/t1.jpg"></li>
 <li>title 2 <img src="/t2.jpg"></li>
 <li>title 3 <img src="/t3.jpg"></li>
 <li>title 4 <img src="/t4.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

I use ajax to call in more titles.

What would be the best way to copy the HTML from the page and fill it in with data from the ajax response?

On initial load should I clone and store a copy of an li (with the data stripped out), then clone this and output it to the page on my ajax response?

Is there a better way?

Please note, I do not wish to write HTML directly into my JS.

Comment: i normally use a "hidden" li, without attributes, and clone from it when necesary. but im not sure that it's a good way to do that

Comment: Thanks Jarry, I'll take it onboard, any other opinions would be grateful

Comment: Not a direct answer to the above, but this is where templating engines can come in handy. Bind a repeater to your `li` with a class, once you have data, it'll show it!

Answer (score 0):

Put your piece of "repeatable" code inside a template

```
<script type="text/template" id="something-makes-sense">
<ul>
 <li>title 1 <img src="/t1.jpg"></li>
 <li>title 2 <img src="/t2.jpg"></li>
 <li>title 3 <img src="/t3.jpg"></li>
 <li>title 4 <img src="/t4.jpg"></li>
</ul>
</script>
```

Then use one of any current template engines out there, for instance `underscore`. When having data, just do

```
_.template($('#something-makes-sense').html(), {data: data})
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **[Jquery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)**

If you do don't want to have html in your java script you can load html (rendered serverside)

into page elements